# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' when convert type of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am changing data type in python.
First, my dataset look like:
[image]

I checked the dataset type of each column:

#Output:
[image]

Then when I want to convert the dataset with this code:

```
df_tr = df1_dlq_slice.replace({'C': -1, 'F': -2, 'Z': -3}).astype(int).T
df_tr.head()
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is replace also empty strings (and all another values):

```
df_tr = df1_dlq_slice.replace({'C': -1, 'F': -2, 'Z': -3,'':0}).astype(int).T
```

Or if need convert all another values to `0` after `replace` use:

```
df_tr = (df1_dlq_slice.replace({'C': -1, 'F': -2, 'Z': -3})
                      .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
                      .fillna(0)
                      .astype(int)
                      .T)
```

---

For test problematic values use:

```
df1 = df1_dlq_slice.replace({'C': -1, 'F': -2, 'Z': -3})

s = df1.stack()
L = s[pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').isna()].unique().tolist()
print (L)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Still got the same error

Comment: @AnwarSanusi - error is same? There is no space between `''` like `' '` ?

Comment: @AnwarSanusi - Answer was edited, what is `print (L)` in your real data?

Comment: Got it. It solved by giving a space like '  '. Thanks